# how to delete '\\' entry in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table category which has two filed `id (auto increment)`  and `catname (string)`

In some particular entry it has entered my user like

```
id | catname

 1 | \\
 2 | abcd
 3 | \\
 4 | >> asd
 5 | \\
 6 | \\
 7 | \\
```

I want to delete this `\\` entry but it is not found by `select` query

How do I delete this `\\` entry ?

And I also use 'php' so any way to delete `\\` entry by `php` or by `phpmyadmin` panel please help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### You can use this query:

```
DELETE FROM `cat` WHERE `catname` = '\\\\';
```

#### Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef33d/1

Comment: thank you, i don't know that the real entry in database is `\\\\`

so thanks, to soved my prob

Answer (score 2):

you can also check the values at the time of post by using "trim" or "str_replace"

trim will remove all of your whitespaces and and other characters at the beginning of the string
or you can use str_replace

The str_replace() function replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string

"mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject <, int &$count > )"

This function works by the following rules:

- If the string to be searched is an array, it returns an array
- If the string to be searched is an array, find and replace is performed with every array element
- If both find and replace are arrays, and replace has fewer elements than find, an empty string will be used as replace
- If find is an array and replace is a string, the replace string will be used for every find value

Examples:

```
<?php 
echo str_replace("world","Peter","Hello world!"); 
?> 

output: Hello Peter! 


<?php 
$arr = array("blue","red","green","yellow"); 
print_r(str_replace("red","pink",$arr,$i)); 
echo "Replacements: $i"; 
?> 

output: Array 
( 
<0> => blue 
<1> => pink 
<2> => green 
<3> => yellow 
) 
Replacements: 1
```

or you can use regular expression "preg_replace" for that you have to learn regular-expresions for details on regular expression follow the link
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

Answer (score 0):

1st way to delete from database is:

```
DELETE TABLE `TABLE_NAME` WHERE `CATNAME` = '\\';
```

This deletes all rows which have '\' entry.

```
DELETE TABLE `TABLE_NAME` WHERE `CATNAME` LIKE '\\';
```